# restored firebase project worked well but later says "This project has been recently deleted. It can be undeleted from the Cloud console"

Tags: firebase, project, restore

I restored the firebase project from cloud console and it showed in both cloud console and firebase console and worked well. But later while in firebase console opening the project it says 'This project has been recently deleted. It can be undeleted from the Cloud console'.

I tried clearing cache.

Comment: Hi! Any update on this problem? I have the same issue. Thanks!